# Only one special character (à) not showing properly in UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I'm a developing a site locally on MacOS (Big Sur 11 Beta) using MAMP and Atom. Local website is build in PHP and uses a MYSQL database. All files are saved in UTF-8, the website shows in UTF-8, the database is in UTF-8 and the MYSQL connection is also UTF-8:

Html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Mysql:

```
utf8-unicode-ci
```

Mysql connection:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($mysql_base, $mysql_user, $mysql_pswd, $mysql_mydb);

...

$setutf8names = $mysqli->query("SET NAMES UTF8");
$setutf8chars = $mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8");
```

Now my problem: I have a lot of names in my database with a lot of different characters. All of them are showing with no problems, like:

```
é
á
í
ć
ú
ü
â
ð
ð
```

The only character NOT showing correct is the "à", which is shown as "� ". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We do not have enough information (and it seems you are assuming too much: where there is not problem). Could you check the bytes you get from your query and print them? Could you include in the output also few characters which have error? Are you sure that in DB the characters are encoded correctly?

Comment: 1. Have you tried a hardcoded `echo "à";` on your site?  And does it show up correct? 2. Have you looked in the database to see wether the `à` might be corrupted in there?

Comment: Thanks Giacomo & Michel. Your tips made me search a little bit further. I found the error causing my problem.

Comment: Check the bytes via `SELECT HEX(col) ...`

Answer (score 1):

The tips from Giacomo and Michel give me some more details. A hardcoded echo worked fine, a direct call to the database (without any use of my own functions) also worked fine. So the problem must be in my code. And I found the problem.

In my function to get names from the database I also used a preg_replace:

```
preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$arr_return ['name']);
```

And after the preg_replace the "à" was change to an

Modifying the preg_replace to

```
preg_replace('/\s+/u', ' ',$arr_return ['name']);
```

(mention the "u") solved the problem. Why the missing "u" only breaks the à and not the other characters is still unknown for me.

Comment: Explanation:  `à` (in utf8) is hex `C3 A0`.  `A0` in latin1 is a "hard space", aka, non-breaking space.  preg_replace _seems_ to be working in latin1, not utf8, hence it removed the `A0`, leaving `C3`, which is "garbled", as indicated by the black diamond.